# Is there a way to have Java call a bash script which calls javac and java?

Tags: java, bash

I'm trying to train a neural network to play Halite 3. The provided interface is a bash script which:
1. compiles my bot
2. calls the binary file with a string to run the bot `java myBot`

I'm trying to run this script from Java to train the network.

I've tried using a `ProcessBuilder` to run the script as well as the binary in the script. Running the script produces no output, and using `echo` I've determined that the program terminates when `javac` is called in the script. Removing that call, it terminates when the program is run.

I've tried calling the program directly as well using `ProcessBuilder`, and this does indeed produce output. The issue is it doesn't run the bots properly saying it can't find the file. I've tried changing the path to be relative to different directory levels as well as the absolute path (the `java` command doesn't seem to like absolute paths?).

Calling the binary directly:

```
            List<String> cmd = new ArrayList<>();
            cmd.add(dir+ "/src/halite");

            // Replay
            cmd.add("--replay-directory");
            cmd.add(dir+"/replays/");

            // Options
            cmd.add("--results-as-json");
            cmd.add("--no-logs");

            // Dimensions
            cmd.add("--width");
            cmd.add("16");
            cmd.add("--height");
            cmd.add("16");

            // Players
            cmd.add("\"java -cp . myBot\"");
            cmd.add("\"java -cp . myBot\"");

            Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).start();
            InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
            Scanner s = new Scanner(is);
            while (s.hasNext()){
                System.out.println((String) s.next());
            }
```

This code does produce a JSON, however, I get an error in my logs saying that the bots do not run.

Comment: You shouldn't include the quotes around `java -cp . myBot` when you use the process builder interface. Those are needed only in a shell environment to signify that the spaces should not be used to split arguments.

Comment: You may have to call the ProcessBuilder's [directory](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory(java.io.File)) method to set the current working directory to be the point where the `java` command should start, or simply specify the correct directory as the `-cp` argument to the `java` command.